# reusing memory space once allocated

Tags: c++, memory-management

Is this program ill-formed?

```
#include <new>

struct A
{
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct B
{
  int a;
};

int main()
{    
  void* p(operator new(sizeof(A)));
  new (p) A();
  static_cast<A*>(p)->~A();

  new (p) B();
  static_cast<B*>(p)->~B();

  operator delete(p);
}
```

Note that we have a guarantee that `p` will be correctly aligned for type `A`. But how about the type `B`? Does the standard mention anything? Is there a standard way to realign `p`?

EDIT: I feel the accepted answer needs more explanation. `operator new` must return a pointer correctly aligned for any object of that size, but of what type is that object going to be? It does not know (and alignment depends upon type), hence it must provide a pointer properly aligned for instances of all possible types and since a "smaller" type's maximum alignment is less than "bigger" type's, the pointer should be correctly aligned.

Comment: Not ill formed because you know the memory location at p can fit B, but certainly odd.  I've seen container implementations for class hierarchies that allocate an array of n slots, each slot being the largest possible class that the array will hold.  After that, placement new can be used to prevent any further memory allocations/indirections even though the container technically holds different types.

Comment: @Aggieboy Certainly, but what about alignment issues?

Comment: Not in this case because the pointer always points to the base address of the memory block.  If you start doing pointer arithmetic on it, then you have to tread a tad more carefully.

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but if you modify the definition of `B` to `struct alignas(A) B { ... };` it should be OK.

Comment: What about `std::align`?

Comment: I don't think it's ill-formed, as other comments have supported. It's probably ill-advised, though. Unless you're extremely careful, it's not going to be long before you forget that that chunk of memory currently contains an `A`, and you try to treat it like a `B`...

Comment: @twalberg I don't think there are any alignment guarantees in the standard.

Comment: @user1095108 No, but a particular *implementation* or *platform* often provides some alignment guarantees. So, while this would definitely sacrifice portability, and thus be "non-standard", it is probably workable on many systems...

Comment: Since both A & B have members of type int, the alignment is ok.  If you want this to work for user defined A & B (like template arguments) then alignment would be a issue.

Comment: I don't believe the standard guarantees that `sizeof(A) >= sizeof(B)`, though it would clearly hold on any sane implementation. Assuming it holds, the rest looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Standard states that the result of `operator new` should be suitably aligned for all types. This, however, does not include extended-alignment types like SSE types.

Comment: Effects: The allocation function (3.7.4.1) called by a new-expression (5.3.4) to allocate size bytes of
storage suitably aligned to represent any object of that size. What if the required size is less than the previously supplied size?

Comment: @user1095108: The alignment of that type can never be more than the maximum alignment of the larger size, so it must be valid.

Comment: Where does the standard say, that alignof(smaller_type) <= alignof(bigger_type).

Comment: @user1095108: It doesn't, because that's not true, but it's also not what I said. The *maximum* Standard-permitted alignment for any type T is `sizeof(T)`. So the *maximum* `alignof(smaller_type)` <= the *maximum* `alignof(bigger_type)`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then `alignof(smaller_type)` could still be greater than `alignof(bigger_type)` and the pointer might still need to be realigned to the correct alignment.

Comment: @user1095108: `alignof(smaller_type)` can be bigger than `alignof(bigger_type)`. But `operator new` isn't aligned for `bigger_type`, it's aligned for *the maximum*, which *is* strictly related to size- as in, the *maximum* of the smaller type must be smaller than the *maximum* of the bigger type.

Comment: If you find the time, please supply pointers into and/or quotes from the standard.

Answer (score -2):

If you use a union of A and B in the sizeof expression, only purists will complain. Like this:

```
union AllocObject {
    A a;
    B b;
};

main() {
    char* p = new char[sizeof AllocObject];
    ...
}
```

However, if you are concerned about `new` performance, you should consider implementing the global allocation operator yourself like this:

```
void* operator new (size_t size) {
    void* result = malloc(size);
    if(!result) throw(bad_alloc());    //Just for standard conformance, unnecessary on Linux...
    return result;
}

void operator delete (void *pointer) {
    free(pointer);
}
```

Of course, you can probably do better, but even the code above is 100 CPU-cycles faster than the builtin version on my machine...

Note that it is enough to have this in a C++ file that gets linked into the program, it is automatically called whenever your program uses the `new` operator.

Comment: operator new must throw on failure, so this isn't standard compliant code.

Comment: @MikeVine: Yes, it probably has to, and you can easily add that. I'll change the answer accordingly.

Comment: why don't you just `throw bad_alloc()`? Also I won't complain as long as you won't try to use `p` as anything other than `char` array.

Comment: -1 because `sizeof` such a union won't help anybody, it would have to be both `sizeof` *and* `alignof`, and also for showing an anecdote with no explanation

Comment: Yes, it's quite inexplanable where the standard implementation looses the 100 cycles... Funny, because `operator new` and `malloc` are defined precisely for the same purpose...